# vx 2002 commodore Seized when going from reverse to drive

Tags: brakes, automatic-transmission, steering, steering-lock, commodore

Tonight, i was reversing uphill to exit a park, put my car into drive and it Seized up. I had no control over steering or my break pedal, it would also not start up again. the only other issue ive had with the car is locking. any suggestions of what it might be? 
note: car is an automatic.

Comment: The engine turned off and the steering was too difficult to turn, is that correct? What do you mean about the brakes?  Couldn't you press the brakes or couldn't you release the brakes?

Comment: no, the steering locked completely and i couldn't press the brakes.